# How to pass input box value to a button action function in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

There is an input box, labeled "Original", on the popup form, containing typed value '105-0045', picture attached. Button click action code is in the function action_replace(). What is the way to pass the input box value to the button function action_replace() when the "Replace" button is clicked?

[image]

Here is my XML code where the input box is defined:

```xml
    <record id="replace_all_in_BOM_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">replace.all.in.BOM.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="20"/>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <label class="text-inline" for="original_name" string="Original" 
            ></label>
            <input name="original_name" id="original_id" ></input>
            <group>
                <field name="default_code" string="Replacement" readonly="1" 
                invisible="0" />    
                <field name="uom_id" invisible="1"  /> 
                <field name="uom_po_id" invisible="1"   />
                <field name="type" invisible="1"   />   
                <field name="categ_id" invisible="1"   /> 
                <field name="name" invisible="1" />             
            </group>
            <button type="object" string="Replace" name="action_replace" />
        </field> 
    </record>

<record id="action5" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Replace all in BOM</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.template</field>           
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="replace_all_in_BOM_form"/>
</record>

<record id="ir_BOM_structure5" model="ir.values">
    <field eval="'client_action_multi'" name="key2"/>
    <field eval="'product.template'" name="model"/>
    <field name="name">Replace all in BOM</field>
    <field eval="'ir.actions.act_window,'+str(action5)" name="value"/></record>
```

Here is the part of py code:

```py
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
        product_obj = self.pool.get('product.template')
        record_ids = context and context.get('active_ids', []) or []
        res = {}
        for product in product_obj.browse(cr, uid, record_ids, context=context):
            if 'default_code' in fields:
                #in 'default_code' is a field name of that pop-up window
                res.update({'default_code': product.default_code, 'name': product.name, 'uom_id': product.uom_id.id,
                            'uom_po_id': product.uom_po_id.id, 'type': product.type, 'categ_id': product.categ_id.id   })
        return res

    def action_replace(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        txt_value = ''
        for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
            txt_value = record.original_id
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'product.template',
            'name': _('Replace all in BOM'),
            'res_id': ids[0],
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': 1212,
            'target': 'new',
            'nodestroy': True,                        
            'context': context
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a button is clicked, the default behaviour of the system is to save the data first and then to execute the button click function. So in the button click you will find 'ids' of current record. Following is the way where you will get the value of that textbox.

```py
def action_replace(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
        txt_value = record.original
        <<your further code>>
    return True
```

Comment: Somehow, it didn't work. I have tried input box's name and id, like so, record.original_name and record.original_id. I have added XML code to the question so you can see the input box definition. I am getting an error: "AttributeError: 'product.template' object has no attribute 'original_id'".

Comment: why did you have the model name as 'product.template'? I think that is the problem? Post your .py code for wizard.

Comment: I have a model 'product.template' because that's the model from the main view from which I am picking up default_code in my popup window. What model do you have in mind? I am not using wizard. It's just a form, act_window that is launched from a menu. In the question content here  I have added more of XML code for this form, and py code. In py code I only have two functions related to this form.

Comment: I think you are going wrong, the pop window means a wizard and I am not getting it why you have used the model name as 'product.template'. You have posted your .py file code, post your class name '_name' attribute of that wizard.

Comment: I don't have any other code for this functionality. I posted here what I have written so far. There is no attribute "_name" I have used for this form. The py code I have posted here is in product_template class. Maybe that's wrong. If not 'product.template' model, what model do you suggest?

Comment: Tell me what is your exact purpose of using that textbox value. What will you do from that. Also, tell are you clicking some menu in the left pane of the screen and popping up this wizard OR are is there an already screen open, and from there clicking on a button is popping up this wizard, if yes than what is the model of that main screen. You need to check out the examples which shows how to manage the wizard.

Comment: The main page (model product.template) has a button with drop down values. When I click on one of the dropdown values, a new form pops up, as per picture. I need textbox value and replacement value (please see the picture) to replace new textbox product name in all BOMs. So, I planned to do that in button's action_replace() hence I need textbox value passed to this function.